# LMDataLoader in fastai

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, fast-ai

I'm trying to use LMDataloader in my nlp project but it always gives the following error

```
NameError: name 'LMDataLoader' is not defined
```

and is not importing either. Is it a version difference in Fastai and has it ben depreciated and if so what can I use instead.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (fastai v2.4 installed):

```
from fastai.text.all import LMDataLoader
```